# $\int fg = \lim \int f_n g$ for any $g \in L^q$ and for uniformly bounded $f_n$ in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^p$ ($1 < p < \infty$) such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and for all $n$, $||f_n|| \leq M$ for some $M$. Then for any $g \in L^q$,  $$\int fg = \lim \int f_n g.$$

Here's what I have:

Due to Egorov, there is an $E$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ on $E^c$. On $E$, we have

$$
\left|\int_Ef_n g-\int_Efg\right| \leq\int_E|f_n-f|\,|g|\leq \|f_n-f\|_p\,\|g\|_q \to0.
$$

I'm lost how to proceed using what I've done. How do I go on from this solution?

Comment: You probably need to restrict $q$ so that $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, in case you used Hölder in the last inequality.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That means I've goe wrong on this one, as the item in my notes doesn't have the restriction on $q$.

Comment: Can I apply the DCT on $|f_n(x) g(x)| \leq M |g(x)|$ and $\lim f_n(x) g(x) = f(x) g(x)$ a.e. to obtain the conclusion?

Comment: It would make sense if $q$ was the Hölder conjugate of $p$. Are you sure there is no typo in the material? Because usually we say that $f_{n}\to f$ weakly in $L^{p}$ if the convergence you wrote applies for all $g\in L^{q}$, where $q$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$. Also about your current proof, $\|f_{n}-f\|_{p}\to 0$ is not entirely trivial either. You could prove that $f_{n}\to f$ almost everywhere + $\|f_{n}\|\leq M$ for all $n$ implies $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{p}$ (using dominated convergence theorem). Note that almost everywhere convergence is not sufficient alone to make it happen.

Comment: Looking at our text (Royden), Holder's inequality was in the section previous to the current section. But the question itself is silent on that.

Comment: About your second last comment: If you would use DCT to argue the following:
$\big| \int f_{n}g-\int fg\big|=\big| \int f_{n}g-fg\big|\leq \|f_{n}g-fg\|_{1}\to 0$, then you would have to show that $|f_{n}g-fg |\leq h$ for some integrable $h$. But do we know that $fg\in L^{1}$?

Comment: Could you please include a bit more context (assumption on the measure space for example)?

Comment: I can’t seem to find this theorem in Royden 4th edition. Can you point me to where you found this theorem? Thanks!